# 'indulge' vs 'indulge in'

Tags: difference

Please feel free to cite better examples; I exemplify with ["indulge a mania"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22indulge+in+the+diversion%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22indulge+a+mania%22) and ["indulge in a mania"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22indulge+in+the+diversion%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22indulge+in+a+mania%22).

What are the similarities and differences between [these ODO definitions](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/indulge)?

> 1(.0). [no object] **indulge in** = Allow oneself to enjoy the pleasure of
>
> 1.3. [with object] **indulge =** Satisfy or yield freely to (a desire or interest):
>
> 2. [with object]  **indulge =** Allow (someone) to enjoy something desired:

1. I see that 1.0 is intransitive and 1.3 transitive, but then what? I exemplify with ["indulge a mania"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22indulge+in+the+diversion%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22indulge+a+mania%22) vs["indulge in a mania"](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22indulge+in+the+diversion%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1&gws_rd=ssl#tbm=bks&q=%22indulge+in+a+mania%22), but please feel free to cite better examples.

2. Please compare 1.3 vs 2? Does 2 apply only to the construct indulge + someone + in +  something?

Answer (score 6):

You "indulge in" an object that gives pleasure:

> I indulged in some chocolate candy.

You "indulge" something that wants something from you.

> I indulged my boss for a bit with small talk before leaving.

The thing you are indulging in the second sense can be a desire or an actual person/object.  That's the difference between 1.3 and 2.

> I indulged my curiosity and peeked behind the curtain

A *mania* is something that takes control of you, so "indulging your mania" means you've decided to let it take control for a while, implying that you've been resisting or controlling it, and that was less pleasurable than letting it go.

Perhaps you like something so much that it throws you into a manic state, thus "indulging in a mania" means you're going to willfully enter this state.